# Как законнекить правильно кнопки?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qpushbutton

Как законнектить кнопки в кастомном `titlebar` так, чтобы они работали и не закрывали мой кастомный `TitleBar`?

Кнопка закрыть должна выполнить функцию закрытия окна (пример: `self.close()`) 
Кнопка сворачивания: `self.showMinimized()`

А полного экрана например:

[image: окно]

```
if self.isMaximized():
            self.showMinimalized()
        else:
            self.showMaximized()
```

Мой код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import pyautogui as p

class Ui_tbWidget(object):
    def setupUi(self, tbWidget):
        tbWidget.setObjectName("tbWidget")
        tbWidget.resize(600, 40)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(tbWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        tbWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        tbWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        tbWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(tbWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
        self.tbWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(tbWidget)
        self.tbWidget_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.tbWidget_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.tbWidget_2.setStyleSheet("QWidget#tbWidget_2{\n"
"    background-color: #009688;\n"
"}")
        self.tbWidget_2.setObjectName("tbWidget_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.tbWidget_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.tbWidget_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.tbWidget_2)
        self.tbWidget_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.tbWidget_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.tbWidget_5.setObjectName("tbWidget_5")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tbWidget_5)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.tbLabel_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Objection.lol', self.tbWidget_5,
            alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)        
        self.tbLabel_6.setObjectName("tbLabel_6")
        self.tbLabel_6.setStyleSheet(
            "#tbLabel_6 {color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 22px;}")
       
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.tbLabel_6)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tbWidget_5)
        self.tbWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.tbWidget_2)
        self.tbWidget_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 40))
        self.tbWidget_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 40))
        self.tbWidget_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);\n"
"    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    border-radius:1px;\n"
"    font-size:18px;\n"
"    font-family:dripicons-v2;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:rgb(49, 48, 53);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#tbPushButton_3:hover{\n"
"    background-color:rgb(232, 17, 35);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"    padding-top:5px;\n"
"    padding-left:5px;\n"
"}")
        self.tbWidget_3.setObjectName("tbWidget_3")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tbPushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.tbPushButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.tbPushButton_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.tbPushButton_3.setObjectName("tbPushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tbPushButton_3, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.tbPushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.tbPushButton_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.tbPushButton_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.tbPushButton_2.setStyleSheet("font-size:13px;")
        self.tbPushButton_2.setCheckable(True)
        self.tbPushButton_2.setObjectName("tbPushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tbPushButton_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.tbPushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.tbPushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.tbPushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.tbPushButton.setObjectName("tbPushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tbPushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tbWidget_2)

        self.retranslateUi(tbWidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(tbWidget)

    def retranslateUi(self, tbWidget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        tbWidget.setWindowTitle(_translate("tbWidget", "Form"))
        self.tbPushButton.setText(_translate("tbWidget", ""))
        self.tbPushButton_3.setText(_translate("tbWidget", "9"))
        self.tbPushButton_2.setText(_translate("tbWidget", ""))


class TitleBar(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_tbWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
  
  
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()  
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.setGeometry(300, 250, 1440, 900)

        def _downloadRequested(item): # QWebEngineDownloadItem
            p.alert(f'Download your file at {item.path()}', 'Request to download file', button='OK')
            item.accept()

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(_downloadRequested)
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://objection.lol"))
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.update_title)

        #self.height = self.screenRect.height()
        #self.width = self.screenRect.width()
        
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('objection.png'))

        self.titleBar = TitleBar()                          
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget) 
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)              
        layout.setSpacing(0)                               
        layout.addWidget(self.titleBar)                     
        layout.addWidget(self.browser) 

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.oldPos = self.pos()              

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.pos().y() > 40:           
            return                         
            
        delta = QPoint (event.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
        self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()
        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
        
    def update_title(self):
        title = self.browser.page().title()
        if  title != "Ace Attorney Objection Maker":
            self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://objection.lol"))
        elif title == "Ace Attorney Objection Maker":
            self.setWindowTitle(title)

    def history(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_F10:
            self.url_start = self.browser.history().backItem()
            print(self.url_start)
            print(self.url_start.url())

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        # если нажата клавиша F11
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_F11:
            # если в полный экран
            if self.isFullScreen():
                # вернуть прежнее состояние
                self.showNormal()
            else:
                # иначе во весь экран
                self.showFullScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание:

- теперь ваши кнопки называются правильно;
- я добавил кнопку, экземпляр которой называется `buttonNormal`;
- `font.setFamily("Webdings")`

Один из возможных вариантов выглядит примерно так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import pyautogui as p


class Ui_tbWidget(object):
    def setupUi(self, tbWidget):
        tbWidget.setObjectName("tbWidget")
        tbWidget.resize(600, 40)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(tbWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        tbWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        tbWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        tbWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(tbWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
        self.tbWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(tbWidget)
        self.tbWidget_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.tbWidget_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.tbWidget_2.setStyleSheet("QWidget#tbWidget_2{\n"
"    background-color: #009688;\n"
"}")
        self.tbWidget_2.setObjectName("tbWidget_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.tbWidget_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.tbWidget_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.tbWidget_2)
        self.tbWidget_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.tbWidget_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.tbWidget_5.setObjectName("tbWidget_5")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tbWidget_5)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.tbLabel_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Objection.lol', self.tbWidget_5,
            alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)        
        self.tbLabel_6.setObjectName("tbLabel_6")
        self.tbLabel_6.setStyleSheet(
            "#tbLabel_6 {color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 22px;}")
       
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.tbLabel_6)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tbWidget_5)
        self.tbWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.tbWidget_2)
        self.tbWidget_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 40))
        self.tbWidget_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 40))
        self.tbWidget_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);\n"
"    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    border-radius:1px;\n"
"    font-size:18px;\n"

# ----> "    font-family:dripicons-v2;\n"                        # <---- убрал

"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:rgb(49, 48, 53);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#closeButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:rgb(232, 17, 35);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"    padding-top:5px;\n"
"    padding-left:5px;\n"
"}")
        self.tbWidget_3.setObjectName("tbWidget_3")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        
        self.closeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)
        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Webdings")
        self.closeButton.setFont(font)
        
        self.closeButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.closeButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.closeButton.setObjectName("closeButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.closeButton, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        
        self.buttonMaximum = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.buttonMaximum.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.buttonMaximum.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
#-        self.buttonMaximum.setStyleSheet("font-size:13px;")
#-        self.buttonMaximum.setCheckable(True)
        font = QtGui.QFont()                                            # +++
        font.setFamily("Webdings")                                      # +++
        self.buttonMaximum.setFont(font)                                # +++
        self.buttonMaximum.setObjectName("buttonMaximum")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonMaximum, 0, 1, 1, 1)

# !!! +++         
        self.buttonNormal = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)      # +++
        self.buttonNormal.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.buttonNormal.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Webdings")
        self.buttonNormal.setFont(font)
        self.buttonNormal.setObjectName("buttonNormal")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonNormal, 0, 1, 1, 1)        
    
        self.buttonMinimum = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.buttonMinimum.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.buttonMinimum.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Webdings")
        self.buttonMinimum.setFont(font)
        self.buttonMinimum.setObjectName("buttonMinimum")  # buttonMinimum tbPushButton
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonMinimum, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tbWidget_2)

        self.retranslateUi(tbWidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(tbWidget)

    def retranslateUi(self, tbWidget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        tbWidget.setWindowTitle(_translate("tbWidget", "Form"))
        
        self.buttonMinimum.setText(_translate("tbWidget", "0"))
        self.closeButton.setText(_translate("tbWidget", "r"))
        self.buttonMaximum.setText(_translate("tbWidget", "1"))
        self.buttonNormal.setText(_translate("tbWidget", "2"))       # +++


class TitleBar(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_tbWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                 # +++ parent
        super(TitleBar, self).__init__(parent)                       # +++ parent
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.buttonNormal.setVisible(False)                          # +++
        self.parent = parent                                         # +++
        self.buttonMinimum.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.buttonMaximum.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.buttonNormal.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.closeButton.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        

        self.buttonMinimum.clicked.connect(self.parent.showMinimized)
        self.buttonMaximum.clicked.connect(self.parent.showMaximized)
        self.buttonNormal.clicked.connect(self.parent.showNormal)
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.parent.close)        
        
        self.parent.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, target, event):
        if isinstance(event, QWindowStateChangeEvent):
            if self.parent.isVisible() and not self.parent.isMinimized():
                # Скрыть кнопку максимизации, если ток максимален
                self.buttonMaximum.setVisible(not self.parent.isMaximized())
                self.buttonNormal.setVisible(self.parent.isMaximized())
        return super(TitleBar, self).eventFilter(target, event)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
  
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()  
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
#        self.setGeometry(300, 250, 1440, 900)
        self.resize(900, 600)

        def _downloadRequested(item): # QWebEngineDownloadItem
            p.alert(f'Download your file at {item.path()}', 'Request to download file', button='OK')
            item.accept()

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(_downloadRequested)
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://objection.lol"))
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.update_title)

        #self.height = self.screenRect.height()
        #self.width = self.screenRect.width()
        
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | 
                            QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('objection.png'))
# +++
        self.titleBar = TitleBar(self)                               # +++ self               
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget) 
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)              
        layout.setSpacing(0)                               
        layout.addWidget(self.titleBar)                     
        layout.addWidget(self.browser) 

        self.oldPos = self.pos()              

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.pos().y() > 40:           
            return                         
            
        delta = QPoint (event.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
        self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()
        
    def update_title(self):
        title = self.browser.page().title()
        if  title != "Ace Attorney Objection Maker":
            self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://objection.lol"))
        elif title == "Ace Attorney Objection Maker":
            self.setWindowTitle(title)

    def history(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_F10:
            self.url_start = self.browser.history().backItem()
            print(self.url_start)
            print(self.url_start.url())

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        # если нажата клавиша F11
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_F11:
            # если в полный экран
            if self.isFullScreen():
                # вернуть прежнее состояние
                self.showNormal()
            else:
                # иначе во весь экран
                self.showFullScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я вам всем обязан. Именно вы помогли написать мне эту программу, огромное вам спасибо...